# Word 2013 - How to remove dropdown arrow and choices from inserted Quick Part?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word, word-automation

In SharePoint I have a Word Document Template ( Content Type).
In it I added a Quick Word 2013 Quick Part but for some reason it keeps its dropdown box showing the other choice when clicked. The others do not do that.
How do I remedy that?

**What it should look like**

[image: Good]

**What it is looking like , showing dropdown and the choices when rolled over**
How do I get rid of the parts in yellow like it ought to?

[image: Bad]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to Office products

Comment: Wow it's part of a SharePoint document library and Word used as a Content Type. I would think as an MVP you would understand that and try to help than comdemn.

Comment: Please close it if it's offensive to you. I'll find my answer.

Comment: It is not offensive to me, It is my opinion as you mentioned Quick part( 3rd party). If you think it falls under this site you can challenge it. Nothing personal. still other reviewers have to review it

Comment: I'm sorry but "Quick Part" is a button on WORD 2013. It is a function.

Comment: http://www.addintools.com/documents/word/images/shot-ribbon-insert-field.png

Comment: oh sorry, i thought it is 3rd party part. i retracted my vote

Comment: No worries. You've help[ed so many people here , we owe you the thanks!! :)

Comment: lol, i am crying now...Thank you for understanding it

Comment: Seriously nothing but respect to you. Without the teachers ( as yourself ) we remain unenlightened and lost. Gracious thank you.